# How to display local folder images in Html string content in windows phone?

Tags: html, string, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have following html content in string format which is formed dynamically.And navigating the html string to the browser using following code.

```
string html=@"<html><head>Image Test</head><body><img
 src=""/images/test01.png""/></body></html>";

phoneBrowser1.NavigateToString(html);
```

page is showing,but the image is not displayed.Please help on this

Comment: Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357485/wp8-webbrowser-control-to-display-images-from-resource-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display such images, you need to copy them to `IsolatedStorage`: [How to display static web content using the WebBrowser control for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431811%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: The link you have provided is with an html file.Can you please help me in using html string with phoneBrowser.NavigateToString("htmlstring");

Comment: Create a new file with that content.

Comment: Do you mean to create a html file with the dynamic string,and storing it in the Isolated Storage. i have tried that too.can please provide me working sample..if you have

Comment: I don't have one, but you can see the link above for more details.